# Efficient method for extracting and categorizing frequent terms from unformatted string column in SQL table

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-analysis, text-processing

I have a string column in a SQL table that contains job titles. This field is filled in by the user and therefore has no formatting.
To obtain a typology of users, I'd like to extract the terms that occur most often in this column.
For exemple:

- Commercial manager
- Commercial Director
- Commercial Administrator

The expected output here would be ***Commercial Executive*** or any other term indicating that this is more than a simple Commercial.

The meaning of the output here is very important, and contrary to what this example might suggest I can't just extract a substring of any kind.

I therefore wanted to use the k-means algorithm, which seems to fit the problem well, given that my data are not labeled in advance and that in the end I want to obtain a grouping of the values that stand out the most, while assigning them a meaning.

In conclusion, do you know if there is a quicker/simpler way than this? Or is this really the most practical method?